# How do I define the type of a pathvariable if I make use of the Spring Data DomainClassConverter in the signature of a REST controller?

Tags: spring-data, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

Given I write a Rest controller like in the exmple provided in the [Spring Data Documentary](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.domain-class-converter) that uses a DomainClassConverter to automatically convert a primary key to a JPA entity:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
class UserController {

  @RequestMapping("/{id}")
  String showUserForm(@PathVariable("id") User user, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "userForm";
  }
}
```

When I am exporting the REST controller method using OpenApi (springdoc-openapi), the resulting documentation will display that the call argument to the REST endpoint to be the entity instead of its primary key.

How can I solve this?